# KDE NEON: Can't upgrade 18.04 -> 20.04: Unresolvable Problem while Calculating Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, kde-neon

This update has been plagued with issues for me. The GUI gives a similar error, but since the first run I've been using the CLI tool `do-release-upgrade`.

## The error

When running the tool, things seem to be going fine until suddenly it crashes with the following:

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.
```

## What I've Tried

- I've confirmed I have no broken packages by:

  - Running `apt-update && pkcon update`
  - Running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
  - Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772653/how-to-list-broken-packages-in-console/772659#772659), I've run both `dpkg -l | grep -E "^..r.*"` and `sudo apt-get check`, both of which returned no text.
- I installed ppa-purge, and I began removing every third-party `ppa` I could think of, but so far nothing has changed.

## My questions

1. How do I find the third-party `ppa`s and packages I have installed?
2. Do I need to simply remove *every* third-party package I have installed?
3. If so, is there an easy way to do this?
4. Is it safe to `ppa-purge` everything listed in the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?
5. Would I be better off starting from a fresh install?

## Update 1

I ran `journalctl -xfe` while running `do-release-upgrade` in another terminal, and discovered that packagekitd is reporting *many* broken packages. This is strange, because I don't think I have any broken packages now. However, from what I understand, my current situation would break while trying to include the new packages for 20.04. I also noticed that many of the "broken" packages were for the `i386` architecture. KDE neon only supports 64-bit installs, and I wonder if they didn't expect people to use multiarch... Anyways, I'm going to start by carefully removing as many `i386` packages as possible and see if that helps. Here's the [full output of journalctl](https://pastebin.com/nh2U9qBJ), in case anyone is curious.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you have any luck?

Comment: unfortunately, I decided it was easier to just back up my data and reinstall linux, so that's what I did :( I've been frustrated with KDE neon so I switched to Kubuntu

Comment: Check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1306361/110089

Answer (score 2):

I ran against the same problem, googled a little and came to conclusion that most people solve the problem by looking at `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` and removing the first broken package.

The excerpt from the file on my machine:

```
Log time: 2021-01-02 18:50:39.243815
Log time: 2021-01-02 18:50:51.559380
Log time: 2021-01-02 18:51:47.706915
  MarkInstall python-is-python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-4 @un uN Ib > FU=1
  Installing python2 as Depends of python-is-python2
    MarkInstall python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN Ib > FU=0
    Installing python2-minimal as PreDepends of python2
      MarkInstall python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN Ib > FU=0
       Removing: python-minimal
        MarkDelete python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > FU=0
    Installing libpython2-stdlib as Depends of python2
      MarkInstall libpython2-stdlib:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN Ib > FU=0
       Removing: libpython-stdlib
        MarkDelete libpython-stdlib:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > FU=0
     Removing: python
      MarkDelete python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) nodejs:amd64 < 12.20.0-1nodesource1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken nodejs:amd64 Depends on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR >
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to nodejs:amd64 2
  Added python-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing nodejs:amd64 via keep of python-minimal:amd64
  MarkKeep python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR > FU=0
...
```

In my case it was enough to uninstall the first broken package - `nodejs`. After that `do-release-upgrade -p` worked well. I've installed the package after the upgrade again.

PS: `ppa-purge` didn't help me. I don't even understand why they suggest to use it as the output of `do-release-upgrade` contains the message saying that the ppa repositories will be deactivated during the upgrade.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I'm not sure if I can accept it though because I'm unable to verify that it works: I've decided to just wipe my computer and reinstall another flavor of GNU linux. I'm not super aware of stackexchange's policies, can you direct me to a place where they talk about what is required to accept an answer?

Comment: @bweber13 You shouldn't accept my answer if you've solved the problem in another way - by reinstalling ubuntu. However I think it was an overkill. I just posted my solution. If someone has the same problem she may find it helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I hope someone else finds it helpful. However, I think calling my solution "overkill" is incorrect. Reinstalling ubuntu took ~1 hour of my time. Copy homedir to external drive, reinstall ubuntu, copy homedir back to my computer, reinstall the 3 applications I use on a daily basis. By the time I had posted this question I had already spent 5+ hours trying to fix my install, and your help did not come until 3 months after I posted it. I don't think we should encourage people to spend many hours chasing a "fix" when a simple hard reset will do the trick.